# I don't understand a solution about Gray Code on LeetCode

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary

Here is the description:

```
******The gray code is a binary numeral system where two successive values differ in only one bit.
Given a non-negative integer n representing the total number of bits in the code, print the sequence of gray code. A gray code sequence must begin with 0.
For example, given n = 2, return [0,1,3,2]. Its gray code sequence is:
00 - 0
01 - 1
11 - 3
10 - 2
**Note:
For a given n, a gray code sequence is not uniquely defined.
For example, [0,2,3,1] is also a valid gray code sequence according to the above definition.****
```

Actually this point is totally a new thing to me,So I look through its introduction on WIKI,then I find a solution (maybe called *Mirror Construct
Methond*),here is a graph about it:[Mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lckai.png). And there is the code writing in this method :

```
// Mirror arrangement
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> grayCode(int n) {
        vector<int> res{0};
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            int size = res.size();
            for (int j = size - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
                res.push_back(res[j] | (1 << i));
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

The problem now is that I can't figure out what's the meaning of `*res.push_back(res[j] | (1 << i))`. I can't understand and use the logic character very well.

Comment: Please don't try to learn C++ from random code samples from the internet. Learn it systematically from a good book instead.

Comment: What exactly you don't understand about that line?

Comment: @Ron: Gray codes are reasonable enough, and the particular line in question is a bit operation of the sort that you expect with Gray codes.

Comment: If you have a question, we can help and answer. But we cannot help you to understand. To understand, you must divide and conquer. Learn what a vector is. Learn what a logical or is. Learn what a shift operator does. Then put everything together and you will understand.

Comment: @MSalters  The sentence in the inner FOR block.

Answer (score 0):

```
res.push_back(res[j] | (1 << i));
```

The parameter passed to res.push_back() is the contents of res[j] with the ith bit set.

If i is 2, the bit representing the value 4 is set. The parameter will also have all the bits that were set in res[j] set.